# Что в данном случае происходит по вызову super()

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Встретил такое применение super для наследования внутренних классов, что в данном случае происходит по вызову super??? Конструктор ???

```
class AandB{
    class B{}
}

class withB extends AandB.B{
     withB(AandB x){
        x.super();  //???????????
     }     
     public static void main(String[] argc){
         AandB ab = new AandB();
         withB wb = new withB(ab);
     }
}
```

Comment: Прямо так и написано? Или, может, все таки `x.super.method()`?

Comment: скинул фото из книги(вложен B в AandB), возмножно не правильно написал, я имео в виду внутренние классы

Comment: x.super.method() если не трудно то поясни пж данную конфигурацию тоже

Comment: `super()` - это вызов родительского конструктора.

Comment: Такой вызов родительского конструктора позволяет указать внешний объект для вновь создаваемого внутреннего объекта.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что для объекта x родительским конструктором является конструктор класса object???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я правильно понял, что для объекта x родительским конструктором является конструктор класса object???

В данном случае не важно какой родительский конструктор у объекта `x`.

`x.super()` - это на самом деле вызов конструктора класса `AandB.B`. А вовсе не `AndB`, как может показаться на первый взгляд.

И вновь созданный экземпляр класса `withB` (который по праву наследства является и `AandB.B`) вкладывается в `x`.

Внутренние объекты имеют неявную связь со внешним объектом.

### Класс `withB`, будучи наследником внутреннего класса `AandB.B` объявляется вне класса `AandB`. Объекты `withB` создаются вне какого-либо объекта `x` класса `AandB`.

### Но объект класса `AandB.B`, должен каким-то образом обзавестись внешним объектом `AandB`.

Вот для этого и придумали такой неестественный вызов родительского конструктора внутреннего класса.

Это соответствует такой условной ситуации:
Если бы у класса `AandB.B` имелся конструктор `B(AandB outer)`, 
тогда мы вместо

```
class withB extends AandB.B {
    withB(AandB x){
        x.super();
    }     
}
```

могли бы написать

```
class withB extends AandB.B {
    withB(AandB x){
        super(x);
    }     
}
```

Так я понимаю эту неестественную конструкцию.

На практике такое, подозреваю, встречается редко, и никто особо не заморачивается рассмотрением этого способа вызова родительского конструктора.
Может кто-нибудь сможет толково перевести на русский язык руководство по вызовам конструкторов в java. Не помню какая там глава.